# Shortcut to change IPv4 properties

Tags: windows, ipv4

I am looking for simple ways to change IPv4 properties of one of my networks and actually I can't find anything promising, just something about netsh. But I think there should be way to create a .bat file or something, to have a "one click" shortcut to change the settings. Could anyone help me with that?

These are changes to be done:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### I am looking for simple ways to change IPv4 properties of one of my network connections.

Use the following commands in a batch file:

```
netsh interface ipv4 set address InterfaceName dhcp
netsh interface ipv4 delete dns InterfaceName addr=all
```

- Replace InterfaceName with the name of the connection you which to change, for example "Local Area Connection"

See [Netsh commands for Interface IP](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490943.aspx) for more information.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [netsh](http://ss64.com/nt/netsh.html) - Configure Network Interfaces, Windows Firewall, Routing & remote access.
- [Netsh commands for Interface IP](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490943.aspx)